# Getting undefined for initvalue in constructor

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have a question in angular2
In the processInput method I am getting undefined for initvalue

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './medbot.component.html',
})

export class Med {
    initvalue: String
    constructor() {
        this.initvalue = "i have initialized this value"
    }


    processInput(message: string): void {
        console.log(this.initvalue)
    }
}
```

it is called from medbot.component.html when we speak something on the microphone

```
<br><br>
<div class="row" width="100%" style="margin:0">
    <microphone [audioInput]="processInput"></microphone>
</div>
```

Comment: when is called this method?

Comment: Does it change anything if you define `initvalue` as `string` instead of `String`? You can also add a semi-colon at the end of each statement.

Comment: When are you calling processInput function? Are you calling it OnInit?

Comment: I have updated details. It is called from the html page, by another component when it has some input

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find out what went wrong. I should have given audioInput like (audioInput) instead of [audioInput] and processInput($event) should have been passed.

```
<br><br>
<div class="row" width="100%" style="margin:0">
    <microphone (audioInput)="processInput($event)"></microphone>
</div>
```